# system image loading in emulator through command prompt

Tags: android, cmd

I have my own system image that i want to load to  an emulator through Command Prompt by the help of commands . How can i do it? How will i come to know that an emulator is using a particular system image through Command Prompt? Is the system image and disk image same? I have created an emulator through command prompt how to load it with my own system image.
I tried below two commands to load Jan_16_SystemImg into my emulator but it didnt work.
1. D:\ELASTIC APP FWK\Jan_16_SystemImg>android create avd -n elastictest1 -t 6 --ab
i armeabi-v7a -initdata Jan_16_SystemImg

1. D:\ELASTIC APP FWK\Jan_16_SystemImg>android create avd -n elastictest1 -t 6 --ab
   i armeabi-v7a -system Jan_16_SystemImg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the android developer site and found the following steps to load sytem image and userdata through command prompt.

1. SYSTEM IMAGE

   > emulator -avd avd_name -sysdir my_system_image_location
2. USER DATA

   > emulator -avd avd_name -wipe-data
   >
   > emulator -avd avd_name -initdata my_userdata_location

Before doing this do not forget check the path variable and all are set for you. If not u can find it on stack overflow previous question.

After i did this i start the emulator with my system and userdata image.